# jquery.mCustomScrollbar with height below 71px

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

I would like to know why an height below `71px` will scroll the div to the bottom?

I need to have `58px` but the scroll should stay on top when the page is loaded.

Anyone know a config to set this?

```
$(".scro").mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollButtons: {
        enable: true
    }
});

.scro {
    width:260px;
    height:71px; // 70px
    background:#333;
}
```

**Update:** if buttons are false, the behavior is correct.

```
scrollButtons:{
   enable:false
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DpvTd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @malihu (author plugin)

```
.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_dragger {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    *height:10px;*
}
```